# Create VBA for selecting a slicer selection

Tags: excel, vba, templates, slicers

I want to use my excel and pivot data as a template. Therefore, all linked data to pivot tables and slicers are emptied when the template is created. After generating the template my slicer setting is lost. Is there any way to make a mandatory and permanent selection for pivot tables? Can you suggest the VBA code?
I want to select different departments within my "Department (Name) Column. For instance a department named "Public Amenities" within the "public Amenities sheet.
Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR7uA.png)

Comment: Show your [mcve]. That is, you need to give it a try and then ask your question in the context of that code. SO is just too busy to be a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't even know where to start, I would suggest first you use the macro recorder to create a slicer, and select some items.

You could use something like this:

```
   ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NameFromSlicer").SlicerItems("NameFromItem").Selected = True
```

To select a specific item in a previously created slicer.
And also

```
    ActiveWorksheet.PivotTables("NameFromPT").Slicers.Add
```

To add a slicer. Note you will have to give the paramethers to the "Add" method.